# Trying to remember anime where antagonists sprayed purple gas from fighter craft

Tags: story-identification

Protagonist was also mentored to be some sort of fighter.  He had to throw balls in the air and "merge" them to prove he was ready.  Rented this in the mid 80's as a kid.